# Force curl to download an empty file

Tags: ftp, curl

In a bash script, I am using `curl` command on linux to download files from a FTP server.

The command I am using is the following (the information about the FTP server connexion is stored in a `.netrc` file):

```
curl -v -netrc "ftp://my.ftp.server/foo/bar.txt" -o bar.txt
```

This is working pretty well, except that if the `bar.txt` is empty (size file = 0).

How do I force `curl` to download the file, i.e. getting a `bar.txt` which is empty?

Comment: If you omit the '-o' option, does it display the file to stdout?  Does the file on the FTP server actually contain anything?  What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: FWIW: If using netrc you need to use two dashes: --netrc.  I would try to use curl --trace-ascii - --netrc "ftp://my.ftp.server/foo/bar.txt" and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a low importance bug, as stated here http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3438362&group_id=976&atid=100976

In a script, you can check that if for an FTP/FTPS transfer the exit code is 0, but the file is not there, most probably the file from the remote server is empty.